# Rapidjson parse in chunks

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm working on a rest client and I want to allocate everything twice. So I decided It would be good to parse directly from my read buffer when I'm sure the content is a json. My so I would like to pass a char* pointer or iterator and a size or an end iterator. Somehow I wasnt able to find a function in rapidjson which supports this.

So is there a function like this and if there is no way doing this, is there an alternative which is as fast as rapidjson?